# indentation and syntax errors Python : I cant run the program as intended due to these issues

Tags: python

I am currently teaching myself Python and I am currently getting indentation errors in my program. When I fix the error on line 7 and indent the line my input `number_input` gets grayed out by my IDE (Pycharm community if that matters) so it is null and other errors appear after fixing the error. My program contains a class called `RetailItem` in the file `q05` and a main called `q05_1test`. The goal of my program is that the user enters either 1, 2, or 3 and displays the corresponding output. For example when the user enters 2 the program should result in Designer Jeans (description), 40 (units), and 34.95 (price) being displayed.

`File q05.py (Class)`:

```
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self, descr, units, price):
        self.__descr = descr
        self.__units = units
        self.__price = price

    # mutator methods
    def set_descr(self, descr):
        self.__descr = descr

    def set_units(self, units):
        self.__units

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price

        # accessor methods

    def show_descr(self):
        return self.__descr

    def show_units(self):
        return self.__units

    def show_price(self):
        return self.__price

        # set string method

    def __str__(self):
        return "Description: " + self.__descr + \
               "\nUnits in Inventory: " + str(self.__units) + \
               "\nPrice: $" + str(self.__price)
```

**Main q05_1test**

```
import q05.py

def main():
#user enters number that determienes what results will be displayed
number_input = input("Enter 1 for item 1 and vise versa for items 2 and 3")
    items_list = []

#list
descr_list = ["Jacket", "Designer Jeans", "Shirt"]
units_list = [12, 40, 20]
price_list = [59.95, 34.95, 24.95]


for number in range(0, 4):
            if number_input == 1:
                for i in range(0, 3, 1):
                    descr = descr_list[i]
                    units = units_list[i]
                    price = price_list[i]
            if number_input == 2:
                for i in range(1, 3, 1):
                    descr = descr_list[i]
                    units = units_list[i]
                    price = price_list[i]
            if number_input == 3:
                for i in range(2, 3, 1):
                    descr = descr_list[i]
                    units = units_list[i]
                    price = price_list[i]

                    item = q05.RetailItem(descr, units, price)

                    items_list = []
                    items_list.append(item)

                for item in items_list:
                    print(item)
                    print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Everything that is part of the `main()` function needs to be indented at minimum one tab. Python's scoping is entirely dictated by indentation. Also, `input()` returns a string and your `if` statements will not work properly because you'll be doing e.g., `"3" == 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent after starting a function.

Changes in `q05_1test.py`:

```
import q05

def main():
    #user enters number that determienes what results will be displayed
    number_input = input("Enter 1 for item 1 and vise versa for items 2 and 3")
    items_list = []

    #list
    descr_list = ["Jacket", "Designer Jeans", "Shirt"]
    units_list = [12, 40, 20]
    price_list = [59.95, 34.95, 24.95]


    for number in range(0, 4):
        if number_input == 1:
            for i in range(0, 3, 1):
                descr = descr_list[i]
                units = units_list[i]
                price = price_list[i]
        if number_input == 2:
            for i in range(1, 3, 1):
                descr = descr_list[i]
                units = units_list[i]
                price = price_list[i]
        if number_input == 3:
            for i in range(2, 3, 1):
                descr = descr_list[i]
                units = units_list[i]
                price = price_list[i]

                item = q05.RetailItem(descr, units, price)

                items_list = []
                items_list.append(item)

            for item in items_list:
                print(item)
                print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here.

**Order**: You are running the `for` loop before the `main` function is called, so `number_input` isn't set when it's trying to be accessed. To fix this, you must move the bottom two lines above the for loop.

However, that won't completely solve the problem. This is because of **scope**. When you set a variable while inside a function, that change is only visible in the function itself. To fix this, use the `global` keyword:

```py
(...)
def main():
    global number_input, items_list
(...)
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) to understand how scope works in Python.